# Is it possible to include virtual resources in a bundle?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

Using MVC4, I've created a controller for css files, so that I can pass a model in to them and use razor syntax within css.

In order not to break existing css files, these special css files do not exist at the path they are requested from.

I've tried to include these files in a bundle, and they do not appear in the page output.

```
bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/site/css").Include("~/Styles/site.css"))
```

> Note that ~/Styles/site.css does not exist on disk.  However, the StylesController handles this correctly and returns the expected content if you ask for it.

My guess is that the bundler sees that there's no file on disk and excludes that path from the output.  But I don't know how to make it not care about that.

Any thoughts on how to get these files to play nice with bundles?

Comment: Are your virtual resources implemented through VirtualPathProvider?

Comment: They are not.  They are accessed as views.  Requesting `/Styles/site.css` would access the `StylesController`'s `Site` action.  This action would return the `/Views/Styles/site.css.vbhtml` view.

Comment: In that case how does expiration will work, because bundles are tracked automatically and last modified date time is used by ASP.NET to create a hash to identify unique bundle version and it has very long caching.

Comment: I had not considered expiration.  I'm not a bundle expert.  Do you have suggestions?

Comment: Bundles have very long expiration, if you wrap your resources around bundle and if your resources will change, bundle will still send old resources. If your resources are virtual, you can use OutputCache to cache resources easily, you don't need bundle. However bundle offers minimization and combines multiple text resources into one, but still major benefit is just caching.

Comment: I know I don't *need* bundle.. it was just a nice way to group things together.  The models (and thus the view output) change very rarely (like, once a year).  This is less of a practical question at this point (since there are viable alternatives) and more an exploration of possibility.

Comment: Then only problem you will face is the expiration, your bundle will not expire and thus your users will get annoyed that even if you modify file, you will not get new file unless you restart your web application.

Comment: Great, I can live with that.  So now it comes back to the original question.  Why won't the bundle include the file?

Comment: Bundle needs a file with expiration and only way you can do is by implementing VirtualPathProvider.

Comment: I've tried something similar to serve javascript (just a string returned by a WebApi controller), but I can't get the route to allow `controller/action.js`, it only accepts `controller/action.js/` (note trailing slash) -- how did you get it to serve for `.css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/site/css")
.Include("~/Styles/site.css",new CssRewriteUrlTransform()))
```

Comment: MVC 4, .NET 4.5 does not appear to have a CssRewriteUrlTransform class. But The Google seems to think this is a solvable problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I hit this roadblock in trying to include the client-side validation bundle in each page without manually including each file. As CssRewriteUrlTransform didn`t seem to do anything for me, I used the next class

```
public class CustomScriptBundle : ScriptBundle
{
    public CustomScriptBundle(string virtualPath, IBundleOrderer orderer)
        : base(virtualPath)
    {
        Orderer = orderer;
    }
    public CustomScriptBundle(string virtualPath)
        : this(virtualPath, new NonOrderingBundleOrderer())
    {

    }
    public CustomScriptBundle IncludeVirtual(string virtualPath)
    {
        this.Include(new BundleResolver().GetBundleContents(virtualPath).ToArray());
        return this;
    }
}
```

p.s. : NonOrderingBundleOrderer is a class that doesn`t order the files included in the bundle alphabetically

Comment: Thank you for sharing.  I am looking forward to trying this solution.